# Unable to install vue-cli using npm

Tags: npm, vue.js, npm-install

I have installed the latest version of `npm` and with that, I am trying to install `vue-cli` using the command

```
npm install --global vue-cli
```

But I am running into issues stated below:

```
    npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to http://registry.npmjs.org/vue-cli failed, reason: write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:827:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pd0ufv\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-02-02T17_02_16_113Z-debug.log
```

I have set my proxy setting as well using

`npm set http-proxy <proxy>`

`npm set https-proxy <proxy>`

but didn't work as well. I am using `npm` version 5.6.0.

Comment: try using `http://` for your schema for both proxies. I'm betting your firewall isn't allowing SSL peering.

Comment: This is how I set it:
`npm config set http-proxy http://kjh-tyuik:3100`, 
`npm config set https-proxy https://kjh-tyuik:3100`. I think this is what you meant to set, right?

Comment: Try setting the `https- proxy` to also use `http://khj-tyuik:300` and not `https`

Comment: Wow! That worked like a charm. Thanks a ton! Please put this as answer and I will mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time this error is because the firewall you're behind doesn't actually support SSL peering but will mimic it if you use their `http` passthrough, so change your `https-proxy` definition accordingly:

```
npm set https-proxy http://example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following steps :

npm cache clean --force

npm install -g @vue/cli